# Multiple nested choices in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Forgive me if I'm not describing this correctly - I'm still learning and I've hit a wall with a problem I'm working on.
I want to create a way (in the Admin backend for now) for users to show the books they like by fiction/non-fiction, age-range, genre(s) and sub-genre(s). So, a user who liked gothic horror books could select fiction>adult>horror>gothic. Or, a user who likes literally all YA books could select fiction>Young Adult and their selection would cascade down to every genre and sub-genre.

I *think* the Choices field option and the MultiSelectField functionality might be a start, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add 'layers' to the choices beyond the categories below, and it seems like an inelegant solution when there could be hundreds of choices. I also don't know how it could be presented in the Admin - ideally with checkboxes that can 'open up' to show the sub-categories beneath them.

```
    GENRE_CHOICES = (
    ('Fiction', (
        ('FCH', 'Childrens'),
        ('FMG', 'Middle Grade'),
        ('FYA', 'Young Adult'),
        ('FAD', 'Adult'),
    )),
    ('Non-Fiction', (
        ('NCH', 'Childrens'),
        ('FMG', 'Middle Grade'),
        ('FYA', 'Young Adult'),
        ('FAD', 'Adult'),
    )),
)
genres = MultiSelectField(max_length = 100, choices=GENRE_CHOICES, null=True)
```

I don't even know the name of what I'm looking for here, so if anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is 'tree structure'. You can define it in multiple ways, for example the way you implement tree in database:

```py
class Tree(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', ...)
```

But there is better approach, which is somehow similar to what you wanted to use in the first place, please refer to [django-mptt TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#treenodemultiplechoicefield)

Comment: Thanks for this - I took a look at the link and it looks like MPTT isn't supported any longer, but it did point me in the direction of a similar project called Treebeard that does exactly what I want: https://pypi.org/project/django-treebeard/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to filter the list of books based on their preferences, then see django-filter
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
(unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to write this to the commertary)

Comment: That isn't what I want, but thanks anyway.